# Creating a table with correct alignment of rows and columns (picture included)

Tags: tables

I am new to using Overleaf and would like to create a table similar to the one that can be seen in the image below:

[image]

My attempt at creating a table similar to this can be seen below, along with the code used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}%DJC-reduces margins around the page
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{equation}

\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}

\title{MATH1180 Coursework 2}
\author{Rasai Stewart}
\date{February 2022}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
    p(x, y) & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
    x & 1
        2
        3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}    
\end{center}
```

As can be seen in the image above, I am having trouble aligning the rows and columns, as the rows are merging with the columns. I would appreciate some help resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX:SE!

- `p(x,y` and `x` are math expression, so they should be in math mode: `$p(x,y)$` and `$x$` or in strict LaTeX notation `\(p(x,y)\)` and `\(x\)`, or the whole table should be in math mode
- for such simple tables you may use `array` incapsulate in equation environment. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \begin{array}{cc|cccc}
            &   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{y}         \\
       \multicolumn{2}{c|}{p(x,y)}
                & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     \\
            \hline
            & 1 & 0.07  & 0.05  & 0.13  & 0.03  \\
         x  & 2 & 0.07  & 0.06  & 0.1   & 0.01  \\
            & 3 & 0.09  & 0.24  & 0.07  & 0.08
        \end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

- or you may consider to use `tabularray` package by which you can write a table containing math variables, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tblr}{cc|cccc}
            &   & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  $y$ 
                        &       &       &       \\
        \SetCell[c=2]{c}    $p(x,y)$
            &   & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     \\
            \hline
        \SetCell[r=3]{c}    $x$  
            & 1 & 0.07  & 0.05  & 0.13  & 0.03  \\
            & 2 & 0.07  & 0.06  & 0.1   & 0.01  \\
            & 3 & 0.09  & 0.24  & 0.07  & 0.08
        \end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

or it can be inserted in equation as is shown in the first example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \begin{tblr}{cc|cccc}
            &   & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  y
                        &       &       &       \\
        \SetCell[c=2]{c}    p(x,y)
            &   & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     \\
            \hline
        \SetCell[r=3]{c}    x
            & 1 & 0.07  & 0.05  & 0.13  & 0.03  \\
            & 2 & 0.07  & 0.06  & 0.1   & 0.01  \\
            & 3 & 0.09  & 0.24  & 0.07  & 0.08
        \end{tblr}
    \]
\end{document}
```

in bot cases result is the same:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking more into how creating tables actually works. Your mistake here is not defining every space in the table (you have to do it even if it's empty).
To achieve the table from your first figure, the TeX code could look like this:

```tex
\begin{tabular}{c c|c c c c}
   & & & y & & \\
   & p(x,y) & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
 \hline
   & 1 \\
 x & 2 \\
   & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: I have changed my code, but the formatting is still incorrect.

Comment: Can you recommend any sources that I can use t learn more about creating tables?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}%DJC-reduces margins around the page
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{equation}

\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}

\title{MATH1180 Coursework 2}
\author{Rasai Stewart}
\date{February 2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
 \begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c|c c c c}
& & & y & & \\
& p(x,y) & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
& 1  &0.07 &0.07 &0.07 &0.07\\
x & 2&0.07 &0.07 &0.07 &0.07\\
& 3  &0.07 &0.07 &0.07 &0.07\\
\end{tabular} 
\label{tab:my_label}
%\caption{my caption}
\end{table}
 
\end{document}
```

*Link on Overleaf* -- https://www.overleaf.com/read/cjxjzsxkjjrr

*Nice tool to create simple tables faster* -- https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

*and one nice book from me, about everything, including tables* -- https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[]
        \begin{tabular}{cl|llll}
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{}          &     & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{y}} \\
            \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textit{p(x,y)}} & 1      & 2     & 3     & 4     \\
            \hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{\textit{x}}   & 1   & 0.07   & 0.05  & 0.13  & 0.03  \\
            & 2   & 0.07   & 0.06  & 0.1   & 0.01  \\
            & 3   & 0.09   & 0.24  & 0.07  & 0.08 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Why `\textit{p(x,y)}}` and `\textit{x,}`, and not `$p(x,y)$` and `$x$`?

Comment: @Zarko Next time ,thanks.